# Apex commandButton Styleclass not applicable

Tags: apex-code, commandbutton

I have two VF pages. One is regular page, the other one style page. The style class 'button1' defined in style page can't be applied to the commandButton in the regular page. I investigate the translated HTML code. The style class of these commandButton is 'btn button1', not 'button1' I define. Why does SalesForce compiler add 'btn' to it? Thanks.

The regular one is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:include pageName="{!$Page.MyStylePage}"/>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="Dismissed" styleClass="button1"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Pursue" styleClass="button1"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The style page is

```
<apex:page id="MyStylePage">
    <style type="text/css">
    .button1 {
            border:  1px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-left: 50px;
            margin-right: 50px;
        }
    </style>    
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

SF style overrides your style, You can change button to

```
<input type="button" style="button1" title="Pursue" />
```